# Package restore fails with Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I have created a blob triggered function app in Azure and added a function.proj file to the project files list. However, when I save the function.proj the package shows the following message and fails with the following message:

```
2020-04-22T09:24:39  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
2020-04-22T09:25:23.354 [Information] Restoring packages.
2020-04-22T09:25:23.385 [Information] Starting packages restore
2020-04-22T09:25:24.188 [Information] System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
2020-04-22T09:25:24.189 [Information] at Internal.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
2020-04-22T09:25:24.189 [Information] at Internal.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
2020-04-22T09:25:24.189 [Information] at Internal.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, String value)
2020-04-22T09:25:24.189 [Information] at System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariableFromRegistry(String variable, String value, Boolean fromMachine)
2020-04-22T09:25:24.190 [Information] at System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(String variable, String value, EnvironmentVariableTarget target)
```

I can see this issue has been resolved on the below github link:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4665

But I am still facing this issue.

Comment: are you using azure functions v2?

Comment: v3, my issue is resolved by re-creating the function, restoring the packages by adding function.proj and then adding the code to run.csx in case anybody is facing the same issue or is interested in the answer, thank you

Comment: you were trying through azure portal?

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the API Management > platform features > configuration and add an application setting with the following:

Key: **DOTNET_ADD_GLOBAL_TOOLS_TO_PATH**
Value: **false**

Azure Functions is caching the packages "globally on the underlying computer", this app setting will force it to cache "locally next to the app".